# How can I use shape corner with tab control in my c# project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0

I have to add tab control similar to shown on visual studio start page. 
How can I add this type of control in toolbox of visual studio and use in my project.

The class name for this control shown is `EzMdiTabs`.

Comment: Its about Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be of help to you to add the control to the toolbox:

http://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/how-to-add-custom-control-in-visual-studio-toolbox/